# How to set image as a background on a button programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to set image as a background on a button programmatically?

Comment: A simple Google search would have given you all the info you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

Comment: are u sure?

bcoz, i cant c backgroundimage as a option in button


it is giving me error
error: request for member 'backgroundImage' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Yes I'm sure. **button** has to be of type **"UIBUtton *"**